# Efficient algorithm for finding largest eigenpair of small general complex matrix

Tags: algorithm, linear-algebra, lapack

I am looking for an efficient algorithm to find the largest eigenpair of a small, general (non-square, non-sparse, non-symmetric), complex matrix, A, of size m x n. By small I mean m and n is typically between 4 and 64 and usually around 16, but with m not equal to n.
This problem is straight forward to solve with the general LAPACK SVD algorithms, i.e. gesvd or gesdd. However, as I am solving millions of these problems and only require the largest eigenpair, I am looking for a more efficient algorithm. Additionally, in my application the eigenvectors will generally be similar for all cases. This lead me to investigate Arnoldi iteration based methods, but I have neither found a good library nor algorithm that applies to my small general complex matrix. Is there an appropriate algorithm and/or library?

Comment: Is eigenpair a bit of a misnomer for a nonsquare system? If you want to use a standard eigenpair iteration like Arnoldi/ARPACK, it might be better to look into the largest eigenvalue of AA' or A'A, then back out the corresponding singular value/vector. Section 8.6 in Golub and Van Loan might be a good place to look for ideas. The power method (applied to A'A or AA') might also be appropriate. I think LAPACK's SVD will be hard to beat.

Comment: @rchilton you _can_ beat SVD if you want less information. See my answer and the more general algorithms of Arnoldi iterations.

Comment: I concede the point - an iterative approach that beelines to the dominant pair has the edge. My final remark was more me just thinking out loud, on a 64x64 or 16x16 system I would just use LAPACK and press on (maybe invoked from multiple threads if I had lots of those systems to solve). I have been displeased with the robustness of Arnoldi/Lanczos methods in practice - but if you're just after the dominant pair maybe it's ok.

Answer (score 1):

Rayleigh iteration has cubic convergence. You may want to implement also the power method and see how they compare, since you need LU or QR decomposition of your matrix.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient_iteration

Following @rchilton's comment, you can apply this to A* A.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of looking for the largest eigenpair is analogous to finding a large power of the matrix, as the lower frequency modes get damped out during the iteration. The [Lanczos algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_algorithm), is one of a few such algorithms that rely on the so-called Ritz eigenvectors during the decomposition. From Wikipedia:

> The Lanczos algorithm is an iterative algorithm ... that is an adaptation of power methods to find eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a square matrix or the singular value decomposition of a rectangular matrix. It is particularly useful for finding decompositions of very large sparse matrices. In latent semantic indexing, for instance, matrices relating millions of documents to hundreds of thousands of terms must be reduced to singular-value form.

The technique works even if the system is *not* sparse, but if it is large and dense it has the advantage that it doesn't all have to be stored in memory at the same time.

**How does it work?**

> The power method for finding the largest eigenvalue of a matrix A can be summarized by noting that if x_{0} is a random vector and x_{n+1}=A x_{n}, then in the large n limit,  x_{n} /  ||x_{n}|| approaches the normed eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue.

**Non-square matrices?**

Noting that your system is not a square matrix, I'm pretty sure that the SVD problem can be decomposed into separate linear algebra problems where the Lanczos algorithm would apply. A good place to ask such questions would be over at https://math.stackexchange.com/.